# How to place any button outside the dialog box

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want a close button that needs to work outside the dialog box.

I want this modal where the close button is outside div.

**Expected:**

[image]

**Implementation:**

[image: what i got]

```
const Component = styled(Box)`
  display: flex;
  height: 528px;
`;

const Image = styled(Box)`
  width: 270px;
  background: url(https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/login_img_c4a81e.png)
    no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2874f0;
  background-position: 50% 85%;
  padding: 40px 33px;

  & > p {
    margin-top: 12px;
    color: #dbdbdb;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
`;

const ReqBtn = styled(Button)`
  background-color: #fb641b;
  text-transform: none;
  height: 48px;
  width: 305px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
`;

const Wrapper = styled(Box)`
  padding: 56px 35px 16px 35px;
  & > p {
    color: #878787;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;

//      <--------------------------------------- styled section ends-------------------------------->

const LoginDialog = ({ open, setOpen }) => {
  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleCloseDialog}
      sx={{
        "& .MuiDialog-container": {
          "& .MuiPaper-root": {
            width: "100%",
            maxWidth: "750px",
          },
        },
      }}
    >
      <Component>

        <Image>

          {/* <Typography
            style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "28px", color: "#fff" }}
          >
            Login
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Get access to your Orders, Wishlist and Recommendations
          </Typography> */}


        </Image>


        <Wrapper>

          {/* <TextField label="Enter Email/Mobile Number" variant="standard" />
          <Typography>
            By continuing, you agree to Flipkart's Terms of Use and Privacy
            Policy.
          </Typography>
          <ReqBtn
            variant="contained"
            sx={{
              "&.MuiButtonBase-root:hover": { backgroundColor: "#fb641b" },
            }}
          >
            Request OTP
          </ReqBtn>
          <Typography>New to Flipkart?Create an Account</Typography> */}

        </Wrapper>

//close button

        <ClearIcon
          onClick={handleCloseDialog}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
        />
      </Component>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default LoginDialog;
```

I tried pasting the <ClearICon> outside <Dialog> component but the issue is the close button came in my navbar position

```
 <>
    <ClearIcon
        onClick={handleCloseDialog}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
      />
    </>
```

[image]

How can I place the CloseIcon outside the dialog box as per provided design?

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```css
.box{
  position:relative;
  background:gray;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.box>.controls{
  position:absolute;
  right:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="controls">
    <button>x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not working the dialog component create scrollbar